# Setting a single spring application context in Mule 4 domain project

Tags: spring, mule4

Our use case is initiate a java object in Domain Mule app via spring. And the object has to be available in referenced Mule projects
This use case was achieved in mule 3. But It seems Mule 4 - each app has come with own spring application context. The object are not visible in referenced mule 4 project
Is it possible to make the object initiated in Domain available in referenced mule 4 project?

Answer (score 0):

Technically Domain app is what is shared in cluster. So, technically, you cannot share Java objects at all. My guess - app should create Java object and pass it to some some flow or process in the Domain app which will modify/initialize this object.

One of the biggest differences between Mule 3 and Mule 4 - total isolation of Java environment in Mule 4. Not only Mule Context is not available and cannot be used but whole Mule Java environment is unavailable. Almost all classes are protected and cannot be used. and, of course, it is all proprietary. So, Mule 3 approaches do not work in Mule 4.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Mule3toMule4Transformation.html